# When I type www.agavepv.com into the browser, why does it show up as not secure? Heroku SSL ACM

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, ssl-certificate, godaddy, heroku

My situation:

If I type `https://www.agavepv.com` or `agavepv.com` the site shows up as secure with the lock. However, if I type the address `www.agavepv.com` it shows up as not secure. What is wrong with my settings?

The Facts:

1. I have the agavepv.com domain registered on GoDaddy.com
2. I am hosting my site on Heroku
3. I have paid hobby dynos which allows me to use ACM for my SSL Certificates
4. I change my DNS settings on GoDaddy and added a CNAME record, the host is `www` and it points to `immense-mullberry-lq60rwg6xrhb0odbnaw2idyi.herokudns.com`
5. I was on with Heroku support regarding my root domain and this is what I was told: `For your root domain agavepv.com you need to point to the DNS target damp-mayflower-pdp4pxd06oq94i5rojwp1rzy.herokudns.com using ALIAS/ANAME record. Although GoDaddy does not support ALIAS/ANAME so you may need to use URL redirects/forwarding for your root domain.`
6. My domain forwarding settings are as follows: 
   [Click to see GoDaddy Domain Forwarding Settings for agavepv.com domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmYX5.png)
7. My Heroku custom domains are setup like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCwWT.png).
8. When I check my certs in the command line using `heroku certs:info` i see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS7IG.png).
9. When I run `curl -vI https://www.agavepv.com` I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qcOO.png).

Currently, when I type in `https://www.agavepv.com` OR `agavepv.com` into the browser, my site shows up as secure. However, if I type `www.agavepv.com` the browser indicates the site is not secure. How do I change my settings so that all three scenarios indicate they are secure and show the lock?

Second, would it be worth it to pay for a domain transfer to another registrar that does allow for ALIAS/ANAME records?

I am very new to this subject so I apologize if what I am missing is very obvious! Someone please help, this has taken up so many hours!

Comment: You probably don’t redirect from insecure plain http to https - modify your server/site configuration to do that for you

Comment: @HermanB thank you. As mentioned, I am kind of a noob in this department so can you please add more color to your statement? How would I go by doing that?

Comment: `HTTP` redirects are sent by the web server. The main question is: what web server configuration do you have access to?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz [This](https://github.com/TheGreekCuban/agavepv/blob/master/server.js) is the repo link to my `server.js` file. I just now added the `sslRedirect package` but still does not show up as secure when I type `www.agavepv.com.` You can see the `npm` docs for that package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/heroku-ssl-redirect).

Comment: Yes, the module is [5 lines of code](https://github.com/nodenica/node-heroku-ssl-redirect/blob/bd081b53fb769f2b8dc214901bd039e6fb581e09/index.js) altogether. It should work if you are in `production` mode, maybe it takes time to redeploy. Otherwise write a handler that will dump all the `HTTP` headers that the [Heroku proxy server](https://ninenines.eu/) sends you. Maybe they don't send `X-Forwarded-Proto` any more.